# 'Bad bind variable' in a trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I have a problem with my code written with SQL Developer relative to the following trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER AGGIORNA_QTA 
AFTER INSERT ON ACQUISTI 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  update prodotti set qta=:old.qta-(select qtaacq from acquisti
    where utente=:new.utente and prodotto=:new.prodotto and data=:new.data);
END;
```

This is the database table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE PRODOTTI(  
 CODICE NUMBER, 
 NOME VARCHAR2(10), 
 QTA NUMBER, 
 PREZZO NUMBER, 
 PRIMARY KEY ("CODICE"))

CREATE TABLE UTENTI(
 USERNAME VARCHAR2(10), 
 NOME VARCHAR2(10), 
 COGNOME VARCHAR2(10), 
 PRIMARY KEY ("USERNAME"))

CREATE TABLE ACQUISTI(
 UTENTE VARCHAR2(10), 
 PRODOTTO NUMBER, 
 DATA DATE, 
 QTAACQ NUMBER, 
 PRIMARY KEY (UTENTE,PRODOTTO,DATA),
 FOREIGN KEY (UTENTE) REFERENCES UTENTI (USERNAME),
 FOREIGN KEY (PRODOTTO) REFERENCES PRODOTTI (CODICE))
```

The problem is that I keep getting the following error:

```
Error(2,29): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'OLD.QTA'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `old` and `new` pseudorows only exist for the table the trigger is against. For the table you're updating you can just refer to `qta` directly, and it'll use the current value for the calculation:

```
update prodotti set qta = qta - ...
```

You aren't specifying which row in that table to update either, so you need to add something like:

```
where codice = :new.prodotto
```

But then you're trying to select from the same table you're inserting into, so you'll get an ORA-04091 mutating table error. As you're querying based on the primary key you can't be expecting more than one row back, so you don't need to query at all, you can just use the new row's `qtaacq` value

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER AGGIORNA_QTA 
AFTER INSERT ON ACQUISTI 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  update prodotti set qta = qta - :new.qtaacq
  where codice = :new.prodotto;
END;
/
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dd88f/1).

You may find this doesn't maintain the quantity in the master table as reliably as you expect in a multiuser environment. Simultaneous inserts may see the same old `qta` value and lead to lost updates.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are trying to set the variable in the wrong table, ACQUISTI does not have a column named qta but the PRODOTTI table has a column named qta